# Do next to floated elements get padding by default?

Tags: css, css-float, padding

[I have setup a container and three divs inside. First two are floated and third one is not floated](http://jsfiddle.net/jR3bf/). (fourth div is added just to elaborate my question)

[I have changed border of first two divs to be transparent to depict it more clearer that thirdDiv is starting right from the firstDiv while placing content of itself ('THIRD') right after secondDiv.](http://jsfiddle.net/jR3bf/1/)

Content of thirdDiv ('THIRD') is placed right after secondDiv
[image]

And you can see that thirdDiv is actually have border started right from the start
[image]

So, my question is that do next to floated element (thirdDiv) gets padding from that direction by default? As it showing to be 155px in my code.

Comment: In what browser? In FF10 I do not see this.

Comment: Chrome is the fellow that shows this "problem". I don't understand the problem or the question.

Comment: Probably I didn't make my question clear so I have added images.

Comment: Still not clear. Can you make a mockup showing what you think _should_ happen?

Comment: Well, I don't want to correct anything. I just want to learn that if its default behavior of next to floated element to get padding from that direction as I have elaborated in code and images too. I don't want to correct anything but learn about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the nonfloated elements don't get padding by default. the container starts underneath your floated divs. However, the **content** in the div respects the float and is pushed to the right. If you apply `overflow:hidden`to the non-floated container, then it has an "automatic margin", respecting the floated divs. (You can see this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jR3bf/2/) - the left border appears.)

EDIT: effectively it is **like** a padding, although there is no padding!

[Example with overflow hidden](http://jsfiddle.net/jR3bf/3/).

[Example without overflow hidden and no padding](http://jsfiddle.net/jR3bf/5/)

[Example without overflow hidden and padding left](http://jsfiddle.net/jR3bf/6/)

note the border and the placement of the extra text!

EDIT 2: depending on what the greater value is, either the padding defined by your css, or the calculated padding (width of the floats) is being applied. In every case, your defined padding and the "calculated-float-padding" do collapse!

Comment: Well that push isn't same as padding? As I did with fourthDiv? IF its just pushing and no formal padding then [why padded version doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/jR3bf/7/)?

Comment: Exactly. This is also true for background-image as it will start it's position 0 0 behind the floats - not where the "automatic margin" is applied.

Comment: @Shawn Taylor - That push is the combined calculated width of your floated divs. Content will flow around your floats.

Comment: @ShawnTaylor look at the examples, this should make it clear.

Comment: But when padding is explicitly set then why it doesn't take effect but rather seem to collapse with push? http://jsfiddle.net/jR3bf/7/

Comment: because the container actually starts underneath the float, as you can see by the hidden green border. If you look closely at the 3 examples i posted, you should note the difference: The padding pushes all the content of the div to the right, while with no padding applied only the content that would be underneath the floated divs gets pushed to the right.

Comment: I tweaked your code this way http://jsfiddle.net/jR3bf/8/ and now if padding is less than PUSH then it doesn't work. So, what I have learned so far is that NEXT TO floated element starts its container from underneath first floated element BUT accumulative PUSH is calculated and content is PADDED though its not padding in code but its APPEARANCE is same as padding. Now if you explicitly mention padding which is less than PUSH then it doesn't take effect but if its more than PUSH then it takes effect. SO, for understanding it can be taken as PADDING as I first asked in my question. Do you agree?

Comment: I edited my answer some time ago, take a look at it, this should clarify everything, and Yes, a agree with you;)

Comment: You're welcome. Check the answer, if it solved your problem, so that others know your question has been answered.

Comment: BUT here comes one little confusion, why you put overflow:hidden on thirdDiv while it was not overflowing at all and what you made it to hide? http://jsfiddle.net/jR3bf/3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7614/discussion-between-christoph-and-shawn-taylor)